# How do I troubleshoot "Encryption type not permitted" error in Kerberos?

Tags: c++, single-sign-on, kerberos

- Keytab file is created with "Crypto ALL".
- The user in AD with which SPN is created has DES, AES128, AES256 encryption algorithms enabled.(user properties -> Accounts).
- The domain user with which I login to my application has no encryption type enabled
- When I do a klist, the ticket has DES-CBC-MD5 encryption.
- In the client machine(from where I access my application), when I execute gpedit.msc, all encryption types are enabled.

I get the following error when authentication fails:
krbAuthenticate: Major Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information  and Minor Error: Encryption type not permitted

Can you please let me knod if I had missed out any configuration related to encryption types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating krb5.conf file in my server machine to include all the encryption types resolved the problem.